# Android studio generates deprecated activity

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

i've used Android Studio 1.3.1 to create a new TabbedActivity using his templates.

The problem is that it generates an activity using `ActionBar.TabListener` and `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` that are deprecated.

Using google i've checked that the actual standard needs `SlidingTabsBasic` or `PagerTabStrip`in place of TabListener etc..

How can i configure Android Studio in order to use new standard ( with support library ) API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i configure Android Studio in order to use new standard ( with support library ) API?

You don't.

You either wait patiently for some future release of Android Studio to ship with updated templates, or you ignore the templates, or you don't use Android Studio.

Since [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87742), [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82517), and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77945) were closed on September 3rd, I would hope that Android Studio 1.4 or 1.5 will address them.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned **CommonsWare** - the next Android Studio's update will fix this issue

But if you don't want to wait - you can manually change the template in the location:

```
android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities/TabbedActivity/root/src/app_package/*.ftl
```

And be carefull - changing some lines can brake the template! (The generated in Android Studio project will have one-two empty files) So, the first thing - make a backup of all this folder (`plugins/android/lib/templates/`), and you can rollback the files in case of failure.